# how to table view scrolls up automatically when new message load from database

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

i am new to iphone development.actually i am developing chatting like app using database.all data display perfectly but i am trying to scrolls up when new message load in table view from database.in my app right now i have to scroll up manually when new message load.what and where to do editing in my code? i try everything through code but i failed to solve.thanks in advance.

here is my some code...

```
-(void) callAfterFiveSecond:(NSTimer*)timer
{

//here is my PHP that loads new message..
//[self.tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollToPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];//that already tries.

}
   //[self.tbl setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX) animated:NO];//that already tries.
    [url release];
    [jsonreturn release];
       }
   }
```

//some part of my table view method....

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self Message] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


       NSString *message1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@%@", text,@"From:",text1];
        NSLog(@"message1=%@",message1);

 balloonView.image = balloon;
        label.text = message1;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *body = [Message objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [body sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0, 480.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size.height + 25;
    //[self.tbl reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to scroll specific table row of the section :

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for your quick response but its fit to the top even i try to change atScrollPosition:pUITableViewScrollPositionBottom.i use timer to call new message every 5 sec but when i scroll down through your code it again scroll and fit to the top....

Comment: use UITableViewScrollPositionBottom or UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle

Comment: yes,mam i have already do this..mention in above comment that already do this..is there any option to do this?